# The Updateing VBA Excel AddIn dilemma

Tags: excel, vba, macos, reference

I am doing a user application that needs an AddIn which I want to update in the workbook_open event.

Here is my plan:

- Add Reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"
- Delete Reference to old AddIn
- Delete old AddIn if existing
- Copy AddIn from different Folder
- Add Reference to new AddIn

This should be done all while the vbProject is password protected and hidden. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Thisworkbook

'
If common_DB.AddFSOref(wb) Then Debug.Print "Added Extensibility"
If common_DB.AddRegEx(wb) Then Debug.Print "Added Regular Expressions"

UpdateDBAddin
End Sub
```

That is my update code that works without password protection but when adding in the reference in the vbProject password is required. I want to suppress that because my users do not have to worry about that.

```
Public Sub UpdateDBAddin()
Dim UserPath As String
Dim AI As AddIn
Dim AddinSourcePath As String
Dim AddinName As String
Dim Addintitle As String
Dim RefName As String
Dim ref As Reference

RefName = "Ex_Ample_Name"
AddinName = "ExampleName.xlam"
Addintitle = "Example AddIn"
UserPath = Application.UserLibraryPath
AddinSourcePath = "E:\Xample\Path\"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ref In Thisworkbook.VBProject.References
    If ref.Name = RefName Then
    Thisworkbook.VBProject.References.remove ref
    End If
Next ref

If Application.AddIns(Addintitle).IsOpen Then
    Workbooks(AddinName).Close False
End If

If common_DB.IsFile(UserPath & "\" & AddinName) Then
    Application.AddIns(Addintitle).Installed = False
    Kill (UserPath & "\" & AddinName)
End If

Application.AddIns.Add (AddinSourcePath & AddinName)
Application.AddIns(Addintitle).Installed = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Here the VBProject Password is requested from the user, I want to suppress that
Thisworkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile (UserPath & "\" & AddinName)

End Sub
```

**Question: How do I suppress the password when I want to add a new reference to my Vbproject?**

**EDIT1:** Dilemma because it only occures when the project is hidden and I cannot 'debug' in the hold-mode. I narrowed the issue down to the adding of the reference to the addin on the last line of UpdateAddin.

**EDIT2:** This has some funnny behaviour. If you just Cancel the password prompt it works just fine. So the reference gets added. It doesn't matter if you put in the password or if you just cancle it the line gets executed.

Comment: Why do you need the reference?

Comment: @CharlesWilliams because the rest of my application doesn't work without it. I had the reference in when I coded it which means that evertime I call a AddIn function I would need to replace that with AddinModule.AddinFunction throughout the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

So far I do not have a solution, but I found the workaround.
Just leave user to cancel password for a first time.
Reference will be added from file.
Then force the main xlsm to be Saved (can't be opened as ReadOnly)
Upon next run, check  if correct reference with correct name and path is already  referenced. if yes skip adding reference from file .. no password popup.

Anyway I am still looking for a solution how to avoid the first popup. Especially because our users are opening main XLSM in ReadOnly mode ..